# onClick element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to save the input of some fields in variables after a click on a button (I am using Bootstrap btw). This is my function:

```
<script>
  function test () {
    var test1 = document.getElementById("nameown").value;
    javascript.alert( 'test1' )
  }
</script>
```

and this is my button:

```
<div id="button">
        <onclick="test()" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
            Example...
          </a>
        </button>
      </div>
```

When I click on the button nothing happens...

As a annotation: I am a HTML and JavaScript beginner.

Comment: (The javascript.alert) is only for demo purposes

Comment: There are *so* many things wrong with this :/

Comment: If he's a beginner we could be nicer.

Comment: Haha ;). As mentioned I am a beginner. Thank you for your answers. I will try them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see..

1. There's no element with an id of `nameown`.
2. If anything, it would be `window.alert()`, but just `alert()` is fine.
3. You're `alert`ing the literal string `"test1"` instead of the variable.
4. `onclick` is not an element.
5. You don't have an opening `a` tag.
6. You don't have an opening `button` tag.

I think this is what you were going for:

```
<script>
  function test() {
    var test1 = document.getElementById("button").value;
    alert(test1);
  }
</script>

<div id="button" onclick="test()" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
    Example...
</div>
```

There are more elegant ways of doing this, as well as shortcuts, but you'll get there if you stick with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions, I think the answers are all correct. And btw sry for the mess I've created ;). @Jason P: nameown was the name of the input field.

Comment: Don't apologize, we all had to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is incorrect. It should look like this:

```
<div id="button" onclick="test()" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
  Example...
</div>
```

or

```
<button onclick="test()" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
  Example...
</button>
```

I was really caught up in that mess of HTML and didn't pay attention to the script. It is pretty bad. Let me give you a few pointers. Start with HTML and learn the basics. [wcshcools](http://www.w3schools.com) is a start. Then move on to javascript like that you were attempting above. You probably wanted something like this:

```
<script>
  function test() {  //Create the function test 
    var test1 = document.getElementById("nameown").value;  //Get the element with id="name own" and assign it to a variable named "test1"
    console.log(test1); //log the value of the variable "test1"
  }
</script>
```

I went with console.log because it is a way better way to test code. For instance if you looped that function you would have a problem in some browsers. To view the console check out [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for firefox or use the dev console in Chrome or Safari. Learn the dev console. It will come in handy.

Comment: you forgot also `var test1 = document.getElementById("nameown").value;
    javascript.alert( 'test1' )` Variable named `test1`, then use a string in alert (probably instead of variable)...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Also `javascript.alert` isn't a thing

Comment: That is true. I am guessing he wants to alert the value of name own. I will add this to my answer. I was too caught up in that mess of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't have a `<` before `onclick`.  Is that a typo?  Is there a lot of other extra stuff there too?

```
<div id="button" onclick="test()" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
Example...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the tag "a"

```
<div id="button">
  <a onclick="test();" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
    Example...
  </a>   
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
function test () {
  var test1 = document.getElementById("nameown").value;
  alert( 'test1' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 ) Your html is incorrect :

instead of

```
<onclick="test()" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
```

use

```
<button onclick="test()" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
```

2) Use alert() instead of javascript.alert().

3) Add an element with id as "nameown".

In addition Use browser developer tool to know more about javascript errors in console or use Firebug For firefox
http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should also change your javascript to the following to alert the value of the element with id nameown:

```
    <script>
      function test() {
        var test1 = document.getElementById("nameown").value;
        alert( test1 );
      }
    </script>
```

that is, change javascript.alert( 'test1' ) to alert( test1)